# SharePoint List - Highlight list items permanently

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I have a SP list with possibility to select (highlight) multiple items from the list. I'd like the selection to stay permanently active (even after refresh) and remove it only if someone clicks on it.

Is it possible with some SP tweaks to achieve that or should I use javascript? 
Any other possible workarounds?

Thanks for your feedback and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jslink to make the desired item highlighted. This will keep the highlight even after refresh.

> Refer links :
>   https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a
>   http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/13/sharepoint-2013-js-link-tutorial/

For removing the highlight, you can keep the flag. Update the flag when user clicks on it. 
Only thing is if any user clicks on the link, flag gets updated. And then next user who views the list will not see highlighted item.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Isn't it possible just to capture the onclick event and force the item to stay clicked permanently with javascript until someone just click again to remove it?

Comment: it would be possible only if we keep the flag of clicked/unclicked and we can update the flag with help of javascript code.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do it but it looks like it's too complex for my skills. Maybe another approach is to have an additional column "YES/NO" and make it inline editable. Is it possible to make only specific column editable while others stay locked? I just want the users to be able to check a checkbox in the list